# i get an error: "MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload"

Tags: payload, metamask

1. I send the transaction from my JavaScript
2. Metamask opens the transfer-dialog
3. I confirm

I get an error message in metamask

> (inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":3801695059583,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["0xf8ac098504a817c80082753094bd212f85764be5ecdb5d0ca44ed46ac866b352c781c8b844d0679d3400000000000000000000000058f9015d8b36eacbd4d105cb79872992c073583f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000822d45a028d2355a1149fac93070742fc4e14213f441d4a8dfd97611b4de238f1ef70ffaa048f0eed65a9c495ce42229d569d156a7ff4cc206efced1f25e1c779c53f24485"],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert )

I reset the transaction history for the account in Metamask setting.

**Information about the accounts in my html **

Coin:   (obj/adr/data):[object Object]/0xBd212f85764Be5ecDB5d0ca44ed46AC866B352c7/undefined
CoinContract:   (obj/adr/data):[object Object]/undefined/undefined
Coin anzeigen   Minter: 0x6d8c98f8eb01f8f7ee55d25bf01e30fa64333940
Coin erzeugen   Account1    0x6d8C98f8eb01F8f7ee55D25Bf01e30Fa64333940  Saldo1  65764158165999998600    Amount: 0.37
Coin senden Account2    0x58f9015d8B36EAcBD4d105CB79872992C073583F  Saldo2  30997031680000000000    Amount: 0.37
Coin senden Account3    0xBd212f85764Be5ecDB5d0ca44ed46AC866B352c7  Saldo3  0   Amount: 0.37

---

**Calling the transaction from container.js**

```
function CoinSenden (data,adressat) {

  console.log("Coin senden: " + adressat);

  try {

    //
    // Code für ändern ????
    //
    var param1=data.amount;
    var myContract = web3.eth.contract(CoinABI);
    var myContractInstance = myContract.at(CoinContractADR);
    console.log("contract/contractinstanz:" + myContract + "/" + myContractInstance);
    console.log("contract/contractinstanz:" + myContract.address + "/" + myContractInstance.address);
    console.log("para:" + param1 + "/" + "adr:" + ContainerAccount2);
    
    myContractInstance.send(
      ContainerAccount2,param1,
      {from : ContainerAccount2, value: 200, gas: 30000, gasPriceInWei : 1000}, 
      function(err, myContract){
        if(!err) {
           // NOTE: The callback will fire twice!
           // Once the contract has the transactionHash property set and once its deployed on an address.
            // e.g. check tx hash on the first call (transaction send)
           if(!myContract.address) {
               console.log("Phase1- " + myContract.transactionHash) // The hash of the transaction, which deploys the contract
           
           // check address on the second call (contract deployed)
           } else {
               console.log("Phase2- " + myContract.address) // the contract address
           }
            // Note that the returned "myContractReturned" === "myContract",
           // so the returned "myContractReturned" object will also get the address set.
        }
        else {

          console.log("Fehler in der Methode beim Coin senden: " + err);

        }
      });
      
   
    
    console.log("Coin senden fertig.")


  } catch (err) {

    console.log("Fehler beim Coin senden: " + err);
    
  }

}
```

Well, not too much. I want to see that it is working:

1. the committed transaction in ganache
2. the new balance for the accounts

Comment: it seems it has something to do with the amount....wrong type ?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah I also had the same issue. But the answer for me was really simple. I just needed to clear the transaction history in Metamask. Settings -> Reset Account. [image]. The reason is because Metamask saves state internally that tracks the nonce of the local blockchain. When you reset your local blockchain, but *don't* reset Metamask, then it gets confused, and thinks it's trying to send a transaction for a block in the past. But resetting the account clears out that history, and so you're good to go. It doesn't change balances, so it's super fast and easy.

Comment: This works great but this is strange, because re-importing the private key does not work, I thought re-importing private key should automatically reset all accounts on metamask.

Comment: Resetting worked for me.  Thank you @bwest87. 

As at 16 Feb 2023, the relevant reset function is now in Settings->Advanced.  The heading is "Clear activity and nonce data" and the button label is "Clear activity tab data".

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and finally solved it.

The problem is a refresh issue when you change from one Ganache account to another on Metamask. If you do no do a corresponding code refresh in your App.js you will have a null somewhere that results in this error.

In my case for a DApp that buys and sells items, after selling an item successfully when connected to ganache account 0 (coinbase account) on MetaMask, I sell the item, and then switch to Ganache account 1 (or any other ganache account) to buy the Item just sold. Now I kept getting this error and it was bad. On checking my code, i found the from account: App.account was pointed to 0x0 by default and was probably not refreshed after changing Ganache accounts on Metamask (even though you refresh on the browser physically), you need to ensure there is a code refresh to reload items. So you need to rerun your displayAccount function to refresh App.account and ensure it is not null and this Solves the problem: See my code:

```
 App.displayAccountInfo(); //I added this line before the buyItem method could work  
    const transactionReceipt = await itemStoreInstance.buyItem(
        _itemId, {
            from: App.account,// This was null till i added displayAccountInfo() above
            value: _price,
            gas: 5000000
        }
    ).on("transactionHash", hash => {
        console.log("transaction hash", hash);
    });
```

The display account simply recalls eth.getAccounts after you have changed to a different Ganache account on Metamask and assigns this to App.account: see below:

```
displayAccountInfo: async () => {
    const accounts = await window.web3.eth.getAccounts();
    App.account = accounts[0];
    $('#account').text(App.account);
    const balance = await window.web3.eth.getBalance(App.account);
    $('#accountBalance').text(window.web3.utils.fromWei(balance, "ether") + " ETH");
},
```

Apply this to the context of your problem, look for where the null is, and it will solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

This error with rpc-payload can ALSO occur when `Metamask` is connected to a test network using RPC on `localhost` (local node).  The same block to transfers which applies to geth on a machine serving RPC via HTTP will take place.

[image]

If you connect to another RPC serving node on the network the restriction disappears.

[image]

Comment: though this answer does not address the specific problem that this user had one year ago, it directly addresses the issue in the title ("The Question").  Therefore, unless the community considers it off topic and subject to removal, I propose that it stays in this thread, if that's OK.  Tks, tg

Answer (score 0):

Might be it is too later for the answer. But just for the sake of others who come in.
I had the same issue today. And later fixed it.
It was seen due to the incorrect way of creation of the contract instance in the javascript. Please check the way the contract instance is being created.
Well, this could be just one of the situations !!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very small problem and **I did make the same mistake as you do. But I Figure it out**

Just change this

```
{from : ContainerAccount2, value: 200, gas: 30000, gasPriceInWei : 1000}
```

to

```
{from : ContainerAccount2, value: web3.utils.toWei( (200).toString() , 'ether'), gas: 30000, gasPriceInWei : 1000}
```

Then your problem will be solved.

Explanation :
You can not directly send the ether as you did, just convert to the "**Unit**"

Hope you get my point